# How to open the existing file explorer and not a new one

Tags: nautilus, google-chrome, filemanager

I have a file explorer window opened and is in the background of Chrome:

[image: screenshot with file explorer behind chrome]

However, when I click on the file explorer icon on the Launcher, it doesn't open/switch to the already opened window, but instead open a new one:

[image: screenshot with new window opened in front of chrome]

How can I just open/switch to the already-opened file explorer window?

Is this a known behaviour or is it a bug?

Comment: I have had this problem as well! It seems very random and I haven't been able to find any fixes! Hope someone figures this out soon!

Comment: Thanks god someone asked this. I was getting paranoid. Just to mention that this happens both if the already window is a normal `Files` window or if it is a copy file dialog etc.

Comment: Just did some searching and this came up: http://askubuntu.com/questions/324066/how-to-make-the-nautilus-icon-open-the-existing-window-instead-of-a-new-one (2nd answer) Might be worth trying (even though it seems to fail for that person.) Also http://askubuntu.com/questions/324066/how-to-make-the-nautilus-icon-open-the-existing-window-instead-of-a-new-one could be a duplicate...

Comment: Strange, I don't know if this helps, but whenever I hover my mouse over the Firefox icon it displays all open windows and lets me choose. > Edit: Spelling

Comment: How about to switch thru open windows with Alt-Tab ?
Not the expected answer but why bother, at max half a year and a brand new ubuntu will be released...

Answer (score 1):

You may have the "Open each folder in its own window" check box selected in the Behavior tab of File Management Preferences.

```
Select a folder
From the top menu bar, select Edit/Preferences
Behavior tab
Uncheck "Open each folder in its own window"
```

It would help to know which version of Ubuntu you are using; this answer is a guess. Edit your question with the output of this command from the terminal:

```
lsb_release -a
```