# How to make the nautilus icon open the existing window instead of a new one

Tags: unity, nautilus

For some reason sometimes when I have a nautilus window open, then switch to a different window, when I click on the nautilus icon in the Unity bar, it opens a new nautilus window instead of the existing one. Yes the old window is still there, if I minimize the fullscreen window it reveals both of them, and the nautilus icon has two ticks.
I think this question's been asked already, but there's no solutions.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. When I click on the "Files" icon in launcher it opens Nautilus at my `/home/[user]/` (**Home**) folder. If I change focus to some other window and click on the "Files" in Launcher again the window already open (**Home**) comes back in focus.

Answer (score 10):

The other solutions didn't helped me. however, this one did.

**Edit `/usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop`**

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop
```

- replace `Exec=nautilus --new-window %U` with `Exec=nautilus`

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. I tried both of your answers. BTW, this only happens when I'm browsing an external disk (like a flash drive).

Comment: @kelvinsong Perhaps you have to restart afterwards?

Answer (score 10):

I watched a video and it says that the problem can be solved by **NOT clicking** on it , instead you just **scroll** your mouse over the *Files* icon . It worked for me.

Comment: yeah, but it is not a sollution

Answer (score 7):

In my case I solved doing this:

- Unlock from Laucher;
- Press Atl + F1 and search from nautilus, an icon of "Files" will apear, execute it.
- Lock to Launcher;

Done :D

Comment: Sorry, did not work :/

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04 as well.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Similar to William's answer, but this worked for me in 16.04 (the difference is marked with *):

1. Unlock "Files" icon from Laucher (and close out of all open Files windows)
2. Search for "Files" in the Dash Home (tap the "Super" key to bring up the browser bar at the top of the screen that says, "*Search your computer*")
3. *Drag-and-drop the icon onto the Launcher, then right-click and re-lock to launcher
4. Enjoy cluster-free Files windows